# php pcre regular expressions without delimiter

Tags: php, regex, pcre

#### Background / Intro

Generally, regular expressions in PHP, e.g. for `preg_match()`, begin and end with a delimiter character like `/`. Personally I often used `@` instead.

Instead of a delim character one can also use opening and closing brackets like `()`, `{}` or `[]`.

The delimiter char needs to be escaped, when it should be interpreted as a regular character. E.g. `preg_match('@^\w+\@\w+\.\w+$@', $mail)` needs to escape the `'@'` as `'\@'`.

The function `preg_quote(string $str, ?string $delimiter)` accepts `null` for the `$delimiter`, which suggests that regular expressions can be written in a way where we don't have to worry about the delimiter.

With `()` it seems we don't have to worry about the delimiter, because `'('` and `')'` already need to be escaped anyway.

With `[]` and `{}` it is a bit different. While an orphan `'['` causes an error, an orphan `']'`, `'{'` or `'}'` does not.

#### Motivation

For package development, I would like to provide methods where the user can specify regex fragments, without worrying about the choice of delimiter.

E.g. if I would internally use `'/'` as the delimiter, then the user (calling code) would need to escape `'/'` in the provided regex fragment. If I use `'@'`, they can leave `'/'` unescaped, but need to escape the `'@'`. If I use `null` / `'()'`, they would not need to escape anything - I think.

Here is an imaginary example. Please don't ask what `->setFragment()` does, all you need to know is that the second parameter receives a regex fragment (that is, a snippet that can be inserted into a regex).

```php
// If regex like '/../':
$system->setFragment('email', '\w+@\w+\.\w+');  // nothing escaped.
$system->setFragment('dir', '\w+(\/\w+)*');  // '/' escaped.

// If regex like '@..@':
$system->setFragment('email', '\w+\@\w+\.\w+');  // '@' escaped.
$system->setFragment('dir', '\w+(/\w+)*');  // nothing escaped.

// If regex like '(..)':
$system->setFragment('email', '\w+@\w+\.\w+');  // nothing escaped.
$system->setFragment('dir', '\w+(/\w+)*');  // nothing escaped.
```

Another example, more akin to what I am actually doing:

```php
function buildMessageRegex(string $message, ?string $delimiter, array $regex_fragments = []): string {
  $quoted_message = preg_quote($message, $delimiter);
  $regex_body = strtr($quoted_message, $replacements);
  return $delimiter !== null
    ? $delimiter . '^' . $regex_body . '$' . $delimiter
    : '(^' . $regex_body . '$)';
}

// By using $delimiter === null, we don't have to escape '/' or '@'.
$regex = buildMessageRegex('Mail: %mail, Dir: %dir.', null, [
  '%mail' => '\w+@\w+\.\w+',
  '%dir' => '\w+(/\w+)*',
]);
```

#### Question

It seems that `()` is the only way to write a regex where I don't have to worry about the delimiter, and can call `preg_quote($str, null)` with null as the delimiter.

Is this assumption correct?

If so, I could always use `()` as the delimiter and would not need to provide a delimiter option in the methods.

Or am I missing something?

#### Scope

I am not sure if this problem/question is specific to PHP, or applies more generally to PCRE anywhere it is used (in Perl, I assume?).

I am personally interested in the PHP case, but I think it is worthwhile mentioning in a good answer how this applies outside of PHP.

Comment: Why are you calling `preg_quote()` in the first place? If the user is providing a regex fragment, shouldn't the special characters be kept in it? You only use `preg_quote()` if the user input should be matched literally, not as a regex.

Comment: If the user doesn't supply the delimiter, that means you're going to add your own delimiters. So whatever delimiter you use, you can use the same thing when calling `preg_quote()`. I don't see why you care about the `null` case.

Comment: I am not calling `preg_quote()` on the user-provided regex fragments. I may call it in some other part of the process, for some other part of the regex. I only mention it to show that php does support regex where no delimiter needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar I added an example in "Motivation".

Comment: Never mind, now I see that you escaped `@` in the middle one.

Comment: So this isn't about calling `preg_quote()` in your library, but the caller knowing what they need to escape in the fragment that they supply, because it depends on the delimiter that you use.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. I might still call `preg_quote()` in other parts of the process, but in this question I mostly mention it to give an overview of the general regex ecosystem in php.

Comment: I think the solution adopted in Perl is that it's safe to escape any punctuation character. So if you don't know what the delimiter will be, escape everything that could potentially be a delmiiter if you want it to be literal.

Comment: And that's what its `\Q` operator does, I believe.

Comment: Interesting. I now added another example, that is more close to what I am doing. I am using this in test cases to assert message contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your logic that `(` and `)` always need to be escaped is not true. They don't normally need to be escaped inside `[]`, but they do if `()` are the delimiters.

For example:

```
preg_match('/[(]/', "foo(bar", $match);
```

is valid, but

```
preg_match('([(])', "foo(bar", $match);
```

gets a "No ending matching delimiter ')' found" error.

So if you use `()` as delimiters, the caller will need to escape those characters inside `[]`, which isn't normally required.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good catch. So neither `[]` nor `{}` or `()` are a magic bullet. With `preg_quote()`, `null` is still the correct option for those choices, because it will escape all of them anyways. https://3v4l.org/Zc3PK

Comment: Lots of back and forth to get to the essence :)

Answer (score 0):

More a pratical solution than a specific answer to your questions.

Many characters can be used as pattern delimiters including non-printable characters from the ascii range: SOH, STX, ETX, EOT, ENQ, ACK ...

They are unlikely to be found in a string, and even less likely that a user will type them on the keyboard (and if the user is really determined to put a SOH in the pattern, he will probably use the escape sequence `\x01` to see something).

So, you can reasonably build the pattern this way (using SOH for instance):

```
$pattern = chr(1) . $body . chr(1) . $modifiers;
```

If you look for something more meaningful than SOH (Start Of Heading U+0001), you can eventually choose the control character RS (Record Separator U+0030) or EOT (End Of Transmission U+0004). Note that you can't use NUL (U+0000).

Obviously, to be totally sure, whatever the delimiter you choose there are always these two good old solutions: escape it or remove it.